# There are some beautiful flowers / There are beautiful flowers

Tags: determiners

Do these sentences have any difference in their meaning? Does "some" mean in this context - not all flowers are beautiful in this garden for them?

> **There are some beautiful flowers** in the garden.
>
> **There are beautiful flowers** in the garden.

Comment: There are good questions on this site. There are some good questions on this site. Have you looked up the usage of the word "some"?

Comment: @Lambie, Have you looked up Astralbee's answer before you has written your comment? Please don't write any surplus comments.

Comment: I am asking you to look up the word some before asking these open-ended questions and I am being polite. Your questions rarely contain any research.

Comment: @Lambie, Your polite is awesome. I'm looking at that post later.

Comment: From what I saw in Astralbee's answer, "some great results" isn't the same as "some beatiful flowers". Does anyone think otherwise? Then, write it, please.

Comment: @Sergey My answer is very specifically about your 'beautiful flowers'. I think most people would say *all* flowers are attractive. To say "some" are beautiful definitely doesn't mean the others are ugly. I've added a bit of detail to my answer in case that wasn't clear. The word is used in different ways. If I said "some answers on this site are wrong", that's a binary choice - something is either wrong, or right. But beauty is gradeable.

Comment: I keep thinking of Samuel L Jackson's quote in Pulp Fiction "I hear they got some tasty burgers". He doesn't mean that some of the burgers on the menu aren't tasty - he's singling out the ones he's heard about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this kind of context, saying that something is true of "some" doesn't necessarily mean that what is being said does not apply to the others *to a degree*. I would take this particular example to mean that the 'some' referred to are *especially* beautiful, because "beautiful" is a 'strong' adjective associate with excellence or exceptionally attractive qualities. If something wasn't 'beautiful', it could still be 'pretty', or 'attractive'. Your example is about flowers, and I don't know of any unattractive or ugly flowers. They are probably all beautiful to a degree, but saying 'some' are beautiful can be a way of singing out the ones that you have a preference for.

If the speaker were to mean that they only found some beautiful and not others, you would be able to tell from the tone of voice - the word "some" would be emphasised.

Comment: @lambie Some books are fantastic. That doesn't imply that the rest aren't good. Some users here are hypercritical. Not all.

Comment: @lambie Can you tell me the names of some flowers that are not beautiful?

Comment: @Lambie Some men are handsome. Others are bloody gorgeous! My point is that saying "some [x] are [y]" doesn't mean everything else is the *antonym* of [y].

Comment: Yes, some men are handsome. "Others are [x]". That is exactly my point. And in the question "Some flowers are beautiful", the implication is "Others are [x]". Of course, it does not imply an antonym.